# Python requests.get with stream=true frozen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a function like this:

```
def saveImg(url, dir, fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as handle:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            if not response.ok:
                return 1
            for chunk in response:
                handle.write(chunk)
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e)
            return 1
    return 0
```

However I found it occasionally hangs and press Ctrl+c is not useful (I'm using windows powershell to run the script, ctrl+c should interrupt the script instantly), it takes a long time to kill the script run, and the stack trace are as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\self_null\test.py", line 235, in <module>
    runTask()
  File ".\self_null\test.py", line 64, in runTask
    oneTask(currentLink, dir, fileName)
  File ".\self_null\test.py", line 110, in oneTask
    saveRes = saveImg(imgLink, dir, fileName)
  File ".\self_null\test.py", line 196, in saveImg
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 421, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 429, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My environment is Python 3.7 64bit and requests library version is 2.25.1

Any ideas why that request hangs?

Comment: Why don't you wait a bit longer? It seems that there is some part of SSL protocol being handled on Python side (which is slow) and it may take a while before it moves on.

Comment: How long is *long time*?

Comment: From press the ctrl+c to above stack trace shown on the terminal took more than one minute.

Comment: sophros@ For waiting a bit longer, what's your suggestion of waiting (e.g by `sleep`)? How long will be ideal for this wait?